# what is the issue with this char reverse function?

Tags: c++, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

so I wrote this code to reverse one of the names based on the user option the idea is to use another function to reverse and to use pointers but after trying all I could think of my code return the same name not changed the best I could do was changing the first letter of the name to a weird sign.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void reverse(char* A) {
    int count = 0;
    char temp[10];
    for (int i = 0; A[i] != NULL; i++)
        count++;
    for (int i = 0; A[i] != NULL; i++) {
          temp[count]=A[i];
        count--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; A[i] != NULL; i++) {
        A[i] = temp[i];
        
    }
    
}

int main(){
    int x= 0;
    int index;

    char Name_list[5][10];
    
    
    
    cout << "please enter the names of the student  " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> Name_list[i];

        for (int j = 0; Name_list[i][j] != NULL; j++) {
            x++;
        }
        while (x > 10)
        {
            x = 0;
            cout << "you have entered more then the allowed number of characters per name enter another name " << endl;
            cin >> Name_list[i];
            for (int j = 0; Name_list[i][j] != NULL; j++) {
                x++;
            }
        }
        x = 0;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << Name_list[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "please enter the index of the name you want to reverse" << endl;
    cin >> index;
    while (index>4||index <0)
    {
        cout << "you entered incorrect index please enter a number from 0 to 4 " << endl;

    }
    reverse(Name_list[index]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << Name_list[i] << endl;
    }
    
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to trace each line of `reverse` in a debugger?

Comment: A debugger is helpful, but you can also just do this one on paper. Start with a 3 letter word, draw some boxes for array slots, follow your logic, and see where each letter ends up.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but `NULL` is a null pointer constant. It is not a `char` value. It may well work in this code, but the correct value for the string terminator is `’\0’`.

Comment: @Osama, Suggestion: instead of using "char Name_list[5][10];", you can use "string Name_List[5]", and then you can call Name_List[i].reverse()  to reverse the name.

Answer (score 1):

For starters such a function should return a pointer to the result string. That is it should be declared like

```
char * reverse( char *s );
```

Note: do not use variable names consisting from upper case letters.

The type `int` can be not large enough to store length of a string. Instead use the type `size_t`.

```
char * reverse( char *s )
{
    size_t count = 0;
    //...
```

It is totally unclear why there is present an array with the number of elements equal to the magic number 10

```
 char temp[10];
```

To reverse a string there is no need to declare an auxiliary array. Such an approach is principally wrong.

In this for loop

```
for (int i = 0; A[i] != NULL; i++)
```

there is compared an object of the type `char` with the pointer `NULL`. The compiler should issue a message for such a wrong comparison. It seems you mean

```
for (int i = 0; A[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

In any case the introduced variable `i` in this first for loop is redundant because you already has the variable `count`.

As you have the array temp with the fixed size equal to 10 then the both loops after the first loop can invoke undefined behavior even if the length of the source string is equal exactly to 10.

And the result string is not zero terminated.

The function can look the following way.

```
char * reverse( char *s )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    while ( s[count] ) ++count;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < count / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[count - i - 1];
        s[count - i - 1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Or using standard functions you could write the function reverse the following way

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstring>

//...

char * reverse( char *s )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0, n = std::strlen( s ); i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        std::swap( s[i], s[n-i-1] ); 
    }

    return s;
}
```

Pay attention to that there is the standard algorithm `std::reverse`. Using it you could reverse a string the following way

```
std::reverse( s, s + std::strlen( s ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; A[i] != NULL; i++) {
    temp[count]=A[i];
    count--;
}
```

If `i` goes up from 0 to 5, `count` goes down from 6 to 1.

Comment: thanks all i had to do was the -1 for the null i add 2  spots for the null without me noticing it, i immediately got the way of solving it after looking into this code block

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few things.

1. If you want do some string manipulation, look into the  stdlib. Unless you are doing this for class.
2. Your writing everything to the end of the temp. buffer
3. You need to add an extra character at the end of the strings for the null byte (I think this implementation may allow for a seg. fault)

Comment: i know but since i am in a class there are some restrictions